# Out of memory error

Tags: php, mysql

i have this site which keeps on throwing out of memory error based on the error logs. sad thing is i cant reproduce the OOM error both on dev site and production site.

i checked the logs and found out that this only happens when bots crawl the pages throwing the OOM error or if the pages are accessed from google search results.

i would appreciate it if anyone could give me any advice on this. thanks

Comment: It sounds like you need to lower the allowed client connections coming through your web server. I also think this should be tagged for apache or whatever server it is you are using.

Comment: What type of out of memory error is being thrown? Can you provide something from the logs?

Comment: Check if the session id has been included in the search results - if they're all using the same session it could be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this problem is bots trying search terms; if you have a search function on the site, you may want to add it--or any other pages that seem to be having the OOM to the Disallow section of your robots.txt .